# Update db based on checkbox selection(s) in Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, checkbox

In Visual Studio, I have a Repeater. This functions fine. It has checkboxes and labels. If someone checks the checkboxes in the Repeater, I want my **button to be clicked and update my database based on what is and isn't checked**.

My code currently selects ALL fields and updates ALL of them in the database (all rows get set to visible = 0). I want ONLY the CHECKED boxes to get Visible = 0. I need a **WHERE statement that somehow sees only the checked fields**, but I am at a loss of how to do this.

Here is my Repeater:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem></asp:CheckBoxList>
            </td>
              <td> <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
     </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my button:

```
protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in Repeater1.Items)
                {
                    CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)aItem.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
                    foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                    {
                        if (listItem.Selected == true)
                        {
                        sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE FormField SET Visible = 0");
                        sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //do something else
                        }
                    }


                } sqlConn2.Close();

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your SQL. UPDATE without a WHERE will apply to all rows in a table. I'm guessing at your table and data structure, but your solution might look more like this:

```
CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)aItem.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");

foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
  if (listItem.Selected)
  {
    sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE FormField SET Visible = 0 WHERE MyField = '{0}';", listItem.Value);
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  else
  {
    //do something else
  }
}
```